# Can't find file.txt path when running java -jar project.jar, but when i start same program from Eclipse or NetBeans it runs fine

Tags: java, eclipse, cmd, path, filenotfoundexception

```
//This is a method that can take path as argument or use the default one
public static Path getFile(Options options, String[] args, CommandLine cmd, CommandLineParser parser) throws ParseException{
    cmd = parser.parse(options, args);
    Path path;
    if (cmd.hasOption("a")) {
        path = Paths.get(cmd.getOptionValue("a"));
        return path;
    } else {
        Path destFilePath = Paths.get("resources\\file.txt");
        return destFilePath;
    }
}

//This is where i parse the file and where i get Exception when i run it from cmd
public static Map<Integer,Log> parseFile(Path path){
    try(FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(path.toString());
        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(fileInputStream, "UTF-8");
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
    ){ 
        String line;
        int counter = 0;
        Map<Integer,Log> logMap = new HashMap<>();
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] array = line.split("\\|");
            Log log = new Log(array[0], array[1], array[2], array[3], array[4]);
            logMap.put(counter++, log);
        }
        return logMap;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfex) {
        System.out.println("File not found. Check the path and try again!");
        fnfex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ioex) {
        System.out.println("Could not read from file.");
        ioex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

I have a problem, that I'm having trouble to solve. I have a file.txt which i need to read and parse, I have included that file into my project.

When I run my project from Eclipse it runs fine and without Exceptions, but when I try to run the same project from cmd I get `java.io.FileNotFoundException`.

If I move file.txt from my project to lets say Desktop and then enter path like "C:\Users\Desktop\file.txt" , then it runs without a problem from cmd and from Eclipse. I need to have that `file.txt` included in my project

This is what I get only when I run it from cmd, when I run it from Eclipse or NetBeans with same arguments it runs without Exception:

Comment: Please post your code. It looks like the issue is related to `System.getResource` or related methods.

Comment: A .jar file is a single archive file.  Entries in a .jar file are not actual files, just sequences of compressed bytes in the archive, so naturally you can’t read them as files.  Use the Class.getResource method.

Comment: @Yserbius I added the code, and manage to solve the problem. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are running in IDE it is finding the file in the filesystem. When you package the file into the Jar you need to load it from the Jar. Since Jars are Zip archives you can't just load it like a normal file.

Look into `Class.getResourceAsStream()`

You can do something like

```
InputStream in = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("resources/file.txt");
```

Comment: Arguments to Class.getResource and Class.getResourceAsStream are relative URLs.  They *must* use a forward slash (`/`) as a file separator, never a backslash, on all platforms.

Comment: @VGR fixed. I'd just written the path from the linked image without thinking.

Comment: A mistake. This is the first time I'm asking a question. I wanted to add code...Sorry.

Comment: I have changed this part of the code, but now I get NullPointerException.  InputStream fileInputStream =Controller.class.getResourceAsStream("resources/file.txt");
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(fileInputStream)); My brain don't work no more, i spent whole day trying to fix this....

Comment: @xtratic Thank you. You gave me the idea how to solve it. I moved file.txt to src folder (NetBeans) and then, since I'm calling for that file from a static method i used `InputStream fileInputStream = Controller.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("file.txt");` and now its working on IDE and from cmd. Thank you again!